# Mongoimport: Escaping commas in CSV

Tags: python, mongoimport

I am using mongoimport in a python script to import multiple CSV files into my Mongo DB. Some values contain backslash escaped commas. How can I use this to correctly import these files to Mongo? I can't find any specific solutions to this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `mongoimport`, but I do know that if you use `csv.reader`, the backslashes are taken care of during reading. Maybe you could consider using a package specifically designed to read the csv, and then pass that along to `mongoimport`.